# Put the sample results in an array, a hash, etc using ruby and oci8

Tags: ruby, oracle-call-interface

I use `ruby-2.3` and `oci-8 gem`. I want to make the `select query`:

```
stm = "select * from DATASERVICEUSERS t where boss<>100 and loginad is not null" 
res = CONN.exec(stm).fetch_hash do |row|
      #do something with row
end
CONN.logoff
```

How can I query the result of the whole to put for example in an array or hash, instead of cycle pass through each record? I need just a collection of elements of the result of this request.

Answer (score 0):

Oci-8 doesn't provice that. The `.exec` method produces a cursor that you you need to process like your code demonstrates. You can fill up an array with an array of fields or a hash.

Here an example for an array

```
  records = []
  conn.exec(sql) { |record| records << record}

 # records: [["xxxx", "xxxx"], ["yyyy", "yyyy"], ..]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question but I've come across this problem. I'm not as well versed in ruby but oci8 2.2.7 actually provides fetch_hash

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/OCI8/Cursor#fetch_hash-instance_method

here's an example from my use case:

```
records = []
dataCursor = @odb.exec(queryUUNRData)
while((data = dataCursor.fetch_hash) != nil)
  records.push data
end
dataCursor.close
```

the resulting dataset already includes the column names as hash key